# Do I need these repos in my local CentOS YUM mirror?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I'm setting up a local CentOS mirror for three revs of the OS: 5, 6 and 7.

Given that space is a premium, I'd like to pare things down where I can.  With rsync, I'm already excluding ISOs for all and i386 for 6 and 7.

Taking a closer look at 6 and 7, I'm seeing some directories with packages I don't think I'll need.  Specifically:

```
- CentOS 7
    - atomic
    - cloud
    - sclo
    - virt

- CentOS 6
    - SCL
    - cloud
    - sclo
    - virt
    - xen4
```

Looking into each of these, I'm thinking that my centos-minimal LAMP servers won't need them.

Other than being able to say I have a complete CentOS mirror, do I really need to include these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  These were not needed.  Not including these extra repos saved space on the repo server.